# ASP.Net: How do I find this error?

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the following error when I try to run an ASP.Net page. It just popped up during development, and I don't know what the cause is.

"OverflowException Occurred. Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."

The line the debugger breaks on is of absolutely no help at all

```
Dim ApproxDate As TextBox = FormView1.FindControl("CurrentResultDateTextBox")
```

The error is occurring on this line because calling findControl on FormView1 causes it to databind (executes a SQL query to return the dataset). I assume the error lies somewhere in one of the object data sources or possibly one of the grid views on the page, but the debugger won't tell me where. Most of the page data sources are bound declaratively (specified in ASP tags in the source)

Pressing F11 to run past the exception displays the following:

"13712696100373320501120906 is not a valid value for Int32."

The value being shown here is the primary key for the main SQL table used by the page. There are about 10 data sources which use this field. Again, there's no indication of where exactly the error is occurring.

So how can I debug an error like this? Are there commands I can run? IIS error logs? 3rd party software to capture the error? I'll take anything I can get

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: The OnLoadComplete event is fired, and this event calls the FindControl function which causes the binding. What follows is ASP.Net system library calls:

FindControl > EnsureChildControls > EnsureDataBound > FormView.DataBind > DataSourceView.Select > PerformDataBinding > FormView.CreateChildControls > DataBindChildren (lots of this) > ListControl.PerformSelect > ObjectDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect > BuildObjectValue > ConvertType > ParseInt32

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the problem. The trick is to first disable "just my code" in the IDE/Debug settings. Then you can see the system functions on the call stack, and while there is no source code, you can click on these functions to unwind the stack to one of the web controls (in this case the ListControl.PerformSelect function)

If you check the auto variables in the debug window, it will show the control involved in the error. From there I added a watch on the ID property to see which control it was, looked up the data source that feeds it, and found the error.

You can also unwind the stack to the ObjectDataSourceView, look at the dataTable property, and call GetErrors() to see the issues. This returns an array of data rows which are flagging errors; The property RowError will show the error message for any given row.